# MapView inside a ViewPager causing black overlay

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-viewpager, arcgis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ViewPager with Google Maps API v2: mysterious black view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837697/viewpager-with-google-maps-api-v2-mysterious-black-view)

So in my Android project I have a ViewPager containing a Fragment with MapView and a ListFragment. (The idea is to display a list of what's currently on map.)

However, when I switch from the map-fragment to ListFragment, I get a black overlaying box over the ListFragment. This box disappears whenever I repopulate the list (e.g. by clicking a menu item) or if I go into another activity and return. This box also doesn't appear on screenshots.

I have tried repopulating the list right after I transition from the map-fragment to ListFragment but that didn't help.

I should probably mention that I am also able to scroll through the box.

**This is the black overlay box over my app:**

[image: Screenshot]

**This is what I get when I take a screenshot (The correct way):**

[image: Photo of the problem]

Comment: have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837697/viewpager-with-google-maps-api-v2-mysterious-black-view