# Google Maps V2 android black space on scroll

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ViewPager with Google Maps API v2: mysterious black view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837697/viewpager-with-google-maps-api-v2-mysterious-black-view)

I have a fragment using com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView to display a map. The Fragment containing the map is within a scroll view. When I scroll the scroll view, the MapView tends to overscroll and I end up seeing a black background (either top the top or the bottom) which I presume is under the map and which gets displayed due to the over scroll. Is there anyway I can change this black to white or prevent the over scroll completely. I tried setting background but to no avail.

Thank you.

[image: Screenshot of black in maps]

Comment: Thanks Mark, I've seen the bug assumed it maybe a different issue as that was during the loading process.

Comment: Well, IMHO the real problem is putting the map in a `ScrollView`. `ScrollView` does not work well with scrollable contents in general.

Comment: Agreed, I've disabled the gestures on the MapView as well as prevented any horizontal gestures on the scroll view in order to minimize the conflict between map and scrollview