# Android MapView With Sliding Menu Obscures Menu

Tags: android, android-layout, android-mapview, android-maps-v2

I have a map view for android maps api v2 in an activity that uses this sliding menu https://github.com/iPaulPro/SlidingMenu.  The sliding menu works great except for on the map page.  There is a black view covering the sliding menu that is the exact size of the map.  This is an example with the map height set at 100dp to outline what I mean.

[image: View Issue]

If I touch that view it will go away.  How would I get rid of it or make it transparent?  I've tried the requestTransparentRegion() trick.  No dice there.

Comment: Whats this iOS search bar??? That just looks wrong...

Comment: Just following the comps.

Comment: Just look at these one: http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-adding-suggestions-to-search/

Comment: The search isn't the issue here.  The black view on the slideout menu is.  It's obviously attached the maps, but I don't know why.

Comment: I know it's not related to the question, that's why the comment section is there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found this stack overflow post [ViewPager with Google Maps API v2: mysterious black view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837697/viewpager-with-google-maps-api-v2-mysterious-black-view) and used this class in place of the normal map fragment.

```
package com.myapp.gms.maps;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

/**
 * @author btate
 */
public class TransparentSupportMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

    public TransparentSupportMapFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                                 ViewGroup view, 
                                 Bundle savedInstance) {

        View layout = super.onCreateView(inflater, view, savedInstance);
        FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
        frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(
           getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        ((ViewGroup) layout).addView(frameLayout,
            new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
               LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
               LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
        );
        return layout;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more solution to this problem. I am showing MapFragment within another fragment. The MapFragment is dynamically added into the a FrameLayout.

The solution is to use `frameLayout.setVisibility(View.Visible)` and `frameLayout.setVisibility(View.Gone)` on open and close events of sliding menu. It doesn't require an extra view to be added. And the black area is completely gone.

```
getSlidingMenu().setOnOpenListener(
    new OnOpenListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOpen() {
            frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
);

getSlidingMenu().setOnClosedListener(
    new OnClosedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClosed() {
            frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

TransparentSupportMapFragment solved the problem for android 2.3.7
Thank you!