# Blank screen on SlidingMenu when using with Fragment (GMap)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragmentactivity, android-maps-v2, android-sliding

So i use SlidingMenu library with a FragmentActivity in my app.

There is a GoogleMap in the layout and a menu on the left side with some content.
When i pull the menu to see it, there is a big black rectangle there, covering my sliding menu content. After i click it once, it is disapearing.

Can anybody has something to say about this?
[image: A simple map.]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on android 2.3.7 but not in 3.x or later versions. After rotating the view the menu renders fine after.

I found a solution using a custom TransparentSupportMapFragment from: [Android MapView With Sliding Menu Obscures Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841272/android-mapview-with-sliding-menu-obscures-menu/17607581)

Answer (score 1):

Fragment Black screen issue

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
     </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

     <!-- hack to fix ugly black artefact with maps v2 -->
     <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem.

You may want to have a look at these issues:

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4639

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4659

Maybe you can find a workaround in comments there.

Comment: No the map is fine for me, i got the black area in the sliding menu.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is too old but since I come here by chance and see there is no accpeted answer I will answer this.Hope it help someone someday.

My solution is add a light layout (about 1dp) with transparent background above the "Shopradar" layout of yours. This worked for me,hope it works for you too ;)