# ListFragment - empty list TextView loads . . . eventually

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment, empty-list

I'm using a `ListFragment` to display a `ListView`. The problem is that the `TextView` which is supposed to display when the list is empty does not display immediately. It starts as a black screen and then eventually will load either the populated list or the empty `TextView` (whichever comes first).

I understand that `ListFragment` does not set the empty `TextView` automaticlly like a `ListActivity` and so I have added the empty `TextView` manually with the following code:

```
ListView list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
TextView emptyText = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
list.setEmptyView(emptyText);
```

I would like the empty view to display immediately and then be replaced with the `ListView` if and when it gets populated.

Comment: A list fragment does set the empty view automatically... You just need to call setEmptyText("it's empty!"); to specify the text

Comment: You should be using `ListFragment#setEmptyText()`

Comment: That doesn't work - using setEmptyText() gives me IllegalStateException: Can't be used with a custom content view. This happens even if I remove the empty txt view from the XML and delete the code above.

Comment: Putting <include layout="@android:layout/list_content" /> in your XML will include the listview and empty TextView in your layout with the proper IDs. Then remove the listview/textview you've created previously and keep your custom layout items.. Just set the width and height on it (i didn't want to garble up the comments with it)

Comment: Same error as before - I added your suggestion to the XML for the list fragment, the one with the list view and empty text view, and removed the code above. I get the same error with setEmptyText.

Comment: One suggestion: You cannot use activities view inside your fragment. You should not use getActivity().findViewById()

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was related to the fact that I was using a `SupportMapFragment` in the `ViewPager`. After sliding the views back and forth very slowly I was able to see that the list was displaying under what appeared to be a black screen. After some digging on StackOverflow when the above comments were not fixing the problem I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837697/viewpager-with-google-maps-api-v2-mysterious-black-view). Apparently using a `MapFragment` in a view pager causes a black box to appear over the other `Fragment` in the `ViewPager`.

I cannot tell why, after some time, the black artifact would disapear and be replaced by the empty list or populated `ListView`. However, I was able to fix the problem by placing a view on top of the map with a transparent background as suggested by the post above. Once the black artifact was removed I could see the empty list view instantly.